# Как в Movie Clip положить Bitmap?

Tags: flash, actionscript

У меня проблемка, я сделал скрол 2х3 и теперь в подложки нужно покидать картинки, их я загрузил и кинул в массив, чтоб можно было их отредактировать перед тем, как закинуть в эти подложки, т.к. картинки намного больше. Через loader их не отредактируешь, поэтому в массив загнал, но они не хотят добавляться в подложки, а loader-ом получалось закидывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитесь задавать вопросы. Правильно заданный вопрос содержит половину ответа. "Скрол", "подложки" и "массив" не относятся к теме, если не приводите полный код своего приложения. Не надо думать, что пол-интернета сейчас занимаются точно такой же задачей, как ваша.

Вот так можно изменить размер загруженной Loader'ом картинки, и вывести её как дочерний объект некого MovieClip'а:

```
var B:Bitmap = myLoader.content as Bitmap;
B.width = B.height = 30;
myMovieClip.addChild( B);
```